# Spring Boot JPA Repository IS NULL ,LIKE Not Working

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

I am filtering by name, surname and number. Sometimes I want to search by a single name,sometimes by name and surname, sometimes by all.LIKE and is null operations are not working.

Example

name:Adam surname:Max no:1235464 WORKING

name:Adam surname:Max no:(Null) NOT WORKING

```
        2021-09-13 15:45:48 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

---

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "SELECT U.* FROM USER U  "
            + "LEFT JOIN CV ON U.USERID=CV.USERID  "
            + "JOIN PROFIL P ON P.CV_ID=CV.CV_ID  "
            + "AND(:name is null OR P.name LIKE %:name% ) "
            + "AND (:surname is null OR P.surname LIKE %:surname% ) "
            + "AND (:no is null OR U.no=:no ) ", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<User> findByDynamicQuery(@Param("name") String name, @Param("surname") String surname, @Param("no") String no);
```

Comment: We definitely need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: Can you also post code of your User model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need code of your User model class to verify this, but `oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01722: invalid number` usually means that there was a problem with converting String to number. Because it is not working only if your number is `NULL` then I suspect that you are using primitive types (e.g. `int`, `long`) instead of actual Number classes. If that is the case then replace `int` / `long` in your model with `Integer` / `Long`.

Share more data if it's not the case and we will try to help.